# Numbers of the form $15k+2^n$ include an abundance of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, soft-question

Quite by accident, I noticed that numbers of the form $15k+2^n$ where $k$ is an odd number seem to feature an unusually high frequency of primes among them. Of course, such numbers have no factors of $2,3,5$ which contributes to this bias. Other than that observation, I can find no formula or other explanation which accounts for this bias.

I have only looked at comparatively small values of $k$ (up to $11$) and $n$ (up to $10$). I cannot say if this apparent bias continues to larger values.

**My soft question is:** Have numbers of this form been investigated? If so, where might I find information about them?

Comment: According to [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), there won't be anything special about these numbers, when you plug in enough $k$. You are just getting false impression from the very small number of samples.

Comment: @WhatsUp Numbers of the form $15k+2^n$ for any given $k$ do not form an arithmetic sequence as in Dirichlet. Rather, they sample the arithmetic sequence $15k+2d$. The question becomes not that there are infinitely many primes in the sequence, but that the particular sampling of numbers of a certain form seems to identify primes with a very high frequency.

Comment: For fixed $n$, Dirichlet can be applied to the sequence $(15k + 2^n)_k$. Note that there is a quantitative version of Dirichlet's theorem, in terms of prime density.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: You can write a simple code to investigate for larger values of k and n to see whether your observation is good or not.

Comment: You have picked a set of values that are not divisible by $2,3,$ or $5.$ So you should spect, if purely random, to get about $2\cdot 3/2\cdot 5/4=15/4$ times as many primes of this sort compared to random sampling.

Comment: You only verified extremely small cases. In particular because the numbers here are all coprime to $30$, it is not at all surprising that you observed many primes.

Comment: @Peter I ran some sample numbers up to $k=15$ and $n=15$, and the bias toward primes persisted. But you are right, I would have to look at long stretches of numbers using values of $k,n>100$ to turn my observation into a conjecture. Computation in that range is beyond my resources.  My question asked if such numbers had been studied.

Comment: @KeithBackman Do you want this for specific $k$'s or do you enumerate over both $k$ and $n$ ? Note that we can increase the chance for primes by choosing $k=77$ , for example , because then, prime factors upto $11$ are impossible. So, it is reasonable to allow all $k$'s, but which range is then reasonable for $k$ ?

Comment: @Peter I did look at $k=7$ and $k=11$ for exponents of $2$ being  $n \le 10$, but I was not trying to restrict myself to $k$ values that would create the kind of bias you point to. From the direction the comments are taking, and the lack of a direct answer to my question, I  conclude that numbers of this form have  not been investigated in the past, which is what I wanted to know when I posed the question.